# Open and close divs on click

Tags: javascript, html, image, show

So I made this script that I use to open submenus and display images at the same time.
This is working quite well, but I'm trying to close the previous one when you click on another one.
Is that possible? In other words, you can't have two menus open at the same time.
Thanks for your precious help.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".exposition").on('click',function(){
var hello = $(this).attr('data-id');
$('.photos-evenements').hide();
$('[id='+ hello + ']').show();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(open) {
  
  console.log("ping");
  
  $('.sub-menu ul').hide();
  $('.sub-menu a').click(function () {
$(this).parent('.sub-menu').children('ul').slideToggle(200);
  });
  
  console.log("pong");
  
  $('.sub-menu a').click(function(open) {
open.preventDefault();
  });
  
});

});
```

```css
.photos-evenements{
  display:none; 
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li class='sub-menu'> <a href='#' class="exposition"  data-id="divId1">1</a>
<ul>
  <li>
    1 openinng (should also close 2 if its open and hide its images)
  </li>
</ul>
  </li>
  <li class='sub-menu'> <a href='#' class="exposition"  data-id="divId2">2</a>
<ul>
  <li>
    2 opening (should also close 1 if its open and hide its images)
  </li>
</ul>
  </li>
  
</ul>

<div class="exposition">
  <div class="photos-ind"><img id="divId1" class="photos-evenements" src="http://follebeton.com/img/Performances%20OK.jpg" data-id="divId1"/></div>
  <div class="photos-ind"><img id="divId1" class="photos-evenements" src="http://follebeton.com/img/333_3.png" data-id="divId1"/></div>
  <div class="photos-ind"><img id="divId1" class="photos-evenements" src="http://follebeton.com/img/333_1.png" data-id="divId1"/></div>
</div>

<div class="exposition">
  <div class="photos-ind"><img id="divId2" class="photos-evenements" src="http://follebeton.com/img/FESTIVAL_JEUNE_VIDEO_1.png" data-id="divId2"/></div>
  <div class="photos-ind"><img id="divId2" class="photos-evenements" src="http://follebeton.com/img/FESTIVAL_JEUNE_VIDEO_4.png" data-id="divId1"/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although not relevant to the question, I'd remove all the duplicate ID's and replace them with some other identifier as this isn't valid HTML and will probably cause problems with your `hello` selector

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, you mean the  `id="divId1" ` ? actually I don't see how I could do that better...

Comment: Yes, maybe put that inside the class attribute instead :) like `class="exposition1 photosevenments"`

Comment: yeah! you are right, actually I was using them since I need to call them later. But maybe just the data-id is enough. 
thanks four your help!

Comment: Just a small tip: There is an html element called 'details' which does exactly what you want natively. It also has a 'toggle' event that you can listen to to trigger other functions.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I wanted to try to use that in jquery to give me more control and to try the exercice, but indeed I usually use the `details` element. 
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add this line

```js
$(this).parent('.sub-menu').siblings().find('ul').slideUp('fast'); // to hide all ul expect this one
```

before

```
$(this).parent('.sub-menu').children('ul').slideToggle(200);
```